# PHPUnit testing Mock's method which takes closure as a param

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit, closures

I write a class which populate DI container with services from yaml file. I have problem with testing a below method:

```
private function parseServices(array $services)
{
    foreach ($services as $name => $attr) {
        $this->container[$name] = function() use($attr) {
            $reflect = new \ReflectionClass($attr["class"]);
            $args = $this->parseArguments($attr["arguments"]);

            return $reflect->newInstanceArgs($args);
        };
    }
}
```

`$services` is an array with services:

```
array(
    serviceName => array(
        class => className,
        arguments => array(...)
    )
)
```

A method `parseArguments()` returns a simple array of arguments for a constructor. For tests `$container` is a mock. I want to test that `container` is called one time for every service witch specific parameters. How can I test this? My idea was something like this:

```
$this->container
     ->expects($this->at(3))
     ->method('offsetSet')
     ->with('demo',$this->callback());
```

But this doesn't work.

## EDIT

The responsibility of this method and even of whole class is populating a container. So maybe the best way to test it is to just check if container is populate correctly? As I wrote in a comment - just don't mock the container but use a concrete implementation. What do you think about it?

Comment: Or maybe the simpliest solution is to use a real Container object in test where `parseServices()` is tested and then I can check state of Container object. I mean that I can check if the Container will return a service which I want. Container class is fully tested. BTW it's Pimple -> http://pimple.sensiolabs.org/ - maybe it'll help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, maybe it's not exactly answer to your question, but could be helpful anyway.

I would design this test different. Since you want to test if proper services are being built it would be easier to use some accessor to get 3rd service and check if it is an object of proper class.

... I just saw EDIT ;) - exactly! With properly designed code it's easier to test class from "outside" point of view. In need such wicked mocking only on legacy systems, when i.e can't inject dependencies.

// Original answer
Could you explain what offsetSet is?

From what I see in your test is that you try to assert that

1. when the method `offsetSet` is called on `$this->container`
2. for the third time
3. it should be called with two parameters:

   1. `'demo'` string and
   2. whatever `$this->callback()` returns (maybe you meant the callback `this->callback` should be passed as 2nd param, not result of calling it?)

Comment: It's a method from ArrayAccess interface -> http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php and please check my comment above.

Comment: Yeah you're right. Method offseSet is called 3rd time with parameters: 'demo' and closure/callback

Comment: I've edited my answer :) Your idea with different approach to testing - is closer to my heart. This is exactly what I would try first.